# NestJS - Casting in DTO?

Tags: mongodb, nestjs

I am trying to create an object in Mongo (via a websockets gateway) with a schema like:

```
export class Issue extends Document {
  @Prop()
  name: string;

  @Prop()
  description: string;

  @Prop()
  project: Types.ObjectId;
}
```

My DTO also refers to the ObjectId type:

```
import { Types } from 'mongoose';

export class CreateIssueDto {
  readonly name: string;
  readonly description: string;
  readonly project: Types.ObjectId;
}
```

The `@MessageBody()` decorator for the gateway seems to pull everything in as a string and thus, the referenced `project` is stored as a string in mongo.

What is the correct way to cast this to an `ObjectId`? Is it just to manually parse the message into its constituents and parse that field specifically?

Comment: waffl Can you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I've been pulling my hair out with this question too, and after trying million things what ended up working for me is using the `Types.ObjectId` from mongoose's `Schema` like the following:

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document, Schema as MongooseSchema, Types } from 'mongoose';

@Schema()
export class Issue extends Document {
  @Prop()
  name: string;

  @Prop()
  description: string;

  @Prop({
    type: MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Project' // Your ref name, i've assumed it.
  })
  project: Types.ObjectId;
}
```

In your DTO do the same, note that I've added an alias so it doesn't collide with `@nestjs/mongoose` Schema.

EDIT

After doing some research i've found that there's a difference between `Types.ObjectId` and `Schema.Types.ObjectId` from `mongoose`, where the 1st one is used in the Model Instance and the latter is used to define Schema fields, therefore @Prop({type}) has to be from `MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId` and the type of the property (project in this case) has to use `Types.ObjectId` and that's how setting `project` to a string representation of the ObjectId gets casted properly.

[Facts Source](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/12385#issuecomment-258393299)

Comment: This solved my issue. It's confusing to have `MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId` and `Types.ObjectId` in `mongoose`

Answer (score 0):

In the payload, your project prop is an id as hexstring format. You can directly save it into database.
In case you wanna save objectId, let getting the project object again and pick object's id as objectId.

But id as hexstring is enough, I thought.